# Increasing the hover area of an image for a sprite

Tags: css, image, hover, sprite

**UPDATE**
Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/mgggf5vo/) with the image and hover event.

I have a sprite image containing 4 "button" images each 30px x 60px - so the total image size is 60px x 120px. Each button is displayed using its proper background offset in the css as shown below.

I want to increase the clickable area of each button, but if I increase padding for the image, more of the image will show than contained in the defined width and height. Can I increase padding or use some other method where the image is still constrained to the amount in height and width?

I do have a containing `a` tag. I am able to increase the clicking area of the buttons by padding the `a` tag, but I still need to give feedback via the img hover that the mouse is in the clickable area.

```
img.prev{
    background:url(../img/buttons.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px scroll;
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
}

img.prev:hover{
    background-position: 0px -60px;
}

img.next{
    background:url(../img/buttons.gif) no-repeat -30px 0px scroll;
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
}

img.next:hover{
    background-position: -30px -60px;
}
```

Comment: A demo would be appropriate here...but *"increasing hit area"* has come up before...try search SO.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will post an demo . All the examples use margin which won't work for a sprite.

Comment: Well there's pseudo-elements and, off the top of my head, `background-clip` might be something you want to look into...but this will depend on the demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D i'm afraid pseudo won't be avalaible for img tag ,just about css given by the op , html still missing

Comment: Yes, but it will for the link wrapper

Comment: I'm also not clear on how an image can have images inside it...or background images...that's weird.

Comment: @Paulie_D and @GCyrillus - thanks for your patience. I have posted a jsFiddle which shows the same image sprite being used for two "buttons" when wrapped in `a` tags. I just want to increase the clicking area without increasing the amount of image shown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pseudo will do .     https://jsfiddle.net/mgggf5vo/6/

catch hover from the link, so it includes the pseudo area.

Te correct attribute for links is `title`, not `alt`.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor:pointer;/* href is missing */
}
a:before {/* give it any size */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 29px;
}
a[title="next"]:before {
  right: 29px;
}
img.prev {
  background: url(http://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/img/slideshow-buttons-large.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px scroll;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
}
a:hover img.prev {
  background-position: 0px -60px;
}
img.next {
  background: url(http://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/img/slideshow-buttons-large.gif) no-repeat -30px 0px scroll;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
}
a:hover img.next {
  background-position: -30px -60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a title="prev">
    <img src="http://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/img/blank.gif" alt="prev" class="prev">
  </a>
  Something Here
  <a title="next">
    <img src="http://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/img/blank.gif" alt="next" class="next">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo `before`. Playing with padding worked but yours is the better solution

Answer (score 1):

OK - I think I've got an answer. It seems I can increase the padding of the containing `a` tag to increase the clicking area and then use the hover event of the `a` tag to set the background for the img. The following css is for the containing `a` tags.

Please let me know if there is a better or another solution.

```
#a-next{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#a-prev{
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#a-next:hover > img{
     background-position: -30px -60px;   
}

#a-prev:hover > img{
    background-position: 0px -60px;
}
```